How can I prevent constant re-rendering of an MUI `DataGrid` on row commit?
Here is how the MUI documentation did it:
const rows = [/* Row Data */]
<DataGrid
rows={rows}
{/* Other Props */} /> /*[1]*/
I admit that this is an excellent way to do it. It is very efficient and DataGrid now handles state on its own.
But it doesn’t work for my use case because rows is dynamic and comes in over the wire. So this is how I did it:
const [rows, set_rows] = useState([])

/* Within some subroutine */
——begin
    let data = await /* A network request that gets the rows */
    set_rows(data)
——end
This works and renders the data fine  but the problem now is that with each row commit, I must call set_rows() to synchronize changes with the GUI. Now guess what happens each time? You guessed it, a GUI re-render.
How do I prevent this re-render?

Permit me to reiterate. In the MUI DataGrid documentation, rows are defined const and passed as input to DataGrid.props.rows making state updates efficient and handled automatically by DataGrid.
In my case, I cannot declare it const and hardcode it because the data is dynamic. I could technically declare it let and mutate the variable after network response but after the DataGrid renders, mutations are no longer detectable by the GUI. Hence I must use useState() so that changes will be reflected in the GUI. If I use useState(), I will have to manage state updates on my own end and the DataGrid re-renders constantly with each state update.

[1] The sample was stripped down excessively to get straight to the point.

You do know that MUI server-side data is still under development: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/8179. Here's the documentation for the planned support: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/server-side-data/

@morganney I know. I actually commented that but I had to delete it. Server Side Data API is still experimental and has so many things it does not offer yet that stops me from using it in production.

So that probably means what they currently offer requires a re-render when new data is available, i.e. it is client-side only. You might want to try something with useRef instead, but overall you may still require a re-render to populate new data. I know your question is about MUI, but this is pretty good with server-side support already: https://gridjs.io/

Exactly @morganney! Good suggestion though but Gridjs needs access to the DOM using Vanilla JavaScript document. I will consider that though. This is what I have been wanting all this while to weigh in on more options.

Please folks bring in more ideas.

React also has useDeferredValue and useExternalStore that may help depending on your goals. They probably won't completely remove a re-render with MUI grid, but might optimize performance a bit.

@morganney they will bring about bad UX because the DataGrid keeps losing focus.

Without rolling your own server-side grid support you're simply choosing the wrong tool for your requirements. I'd seriously consider another option like the one I mentioned earlier.

I have been hoping to come across someone who did this and have ‘em let me in on ‘em secret.

Since it seems you are managing rows, have you tried playing with the key attribute on the Data Grid. passing it a unique value to enforce/control re-render.

I’m sorry @MujeebQureshi I didn’t catch that. DataGrid does not have a key attribute or does it? If you can explain further, please consider writing an answer.

Every react component has a key attribute, which react uses internally to handle states.

Ohh that’s what you meant… the key of a React Element is not a public API. But if you have a good answer @MujeebQureshi please let’s hear it.

I have forked an implementation of you problem here, but I am not seeing re-render loop like you are facing.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-data-grid-forked-778n7d?file=%2Fsrc%2FMyDataGrid.tsx%3A71%2C14

@MujeebQureshi your codesandbox is not public and hence inaccessible. It could be also that it has been deleted and therefore doesn’t exist. I would love to see what you are doing.

Just made it public. can you try again

Sorry if I'm missing something, (I don't know exactly how you trigger it to get the new data) but why you don't use updateRows method? https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-updates/#the-updaterows-method

@Arnau this also creates a re-render. If you are doing something different, consider writing an answer.

If I understood your issue correctly, one solution could be to separate the initial data (rows) from the modified data (modifiedRowsRef).
To prevent constant re-rendering of an MUI DataGrid on row commit while still accessing modified rows, you can try this:

Initial Data: Fetch from an API and store in the rows state.
Modified Data: Stored in a ref (modifiedRowsRef) to avoid causing re-renders when updated.



import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import { DataGrid, GridRowModel, GridColDef, GridValidRowModel } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

interface RowData extends GridValidRowModel {
  id: number;
  lastName: string;
  firstName: string;
  age: number | null;
}

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
  { field: "firstName", headerName: "First name", width: 130, editable: true },
  { field: "lastName", headerName: "Last name", width: 130, editable: true },
  { field: "age", headerName: "Age", type: 'number', width: 90, editable: true },
];

const MyDataGrid: React.FC = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState<RowData[]>([]);
  const modifiedRowsRef = useRef<{ [id: number]: RowData }>({});


  // Check if component is rendered
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("MyDataGrid component rendered");
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulate an API call
    setTimeout(() => {
      setRows([
        { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 35 },
        { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Cersei", age: 42 },
        { id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 45 },
        { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 16 },
        { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: null },
      ]);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  // Function to get the entire data structure
  const getEntireDataStructure = () => {
    const mergedData = rows.map(row => modifiedRowsRef.current[row.id] || row);
    console.log("Entire Data Structure:", mergedData);
    return mergedData;
  };

  // Function to send the entire data structure to the server
  const updateDataOnServer = useCallback(() => {
    const updatedData = getEntireDataStructure();
    console.log("Updated Data:", updatedData);
    // Send updatedData to server
  }, [rows]);

  // Process row update
  const processRowUpdate = useCallback(
    (newRow: GridRowModel, oldRow: GridRowModel): GridRowModel => {
      const updatedRow = newRow as RowData;

      modifiedRowsRef.current = {
        ...modifiedRowsRef.current,
        [updatedRow.id]: updatedRow,
      };

      // Log the current state of modifiedRowsRef
      console.log("Modified Rows:", modifiedRowsRef.current);

      // Update data on the server
      updateDataOnServer();

      return updatedRow;
    },
    [updateDataOnServer]
  );

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { pageSize: 5, page: 0 },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        onProcessRowUpdateError={(error) => console.error("Update error:", error)}
        loading={rows.length === 0}
      />
      <button onClick={getEntireDataStructure}>
        Get Entire Data Structure
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(MyDataGrid);



I assume you would like to update the server-side data on commit, and therefore I added these functions

getEntireDataStructure: Merges the initial data with the modified data to get the complete data structure.
updateDataOnServer: Send the entire data structure to the server.

Conclusion, any state update in ReactNode will trigger a GUI re-render

setNewRows() doesn’t cause newRow value to change quickly but the change is batched for the next re-render (which is what we want to prevent) hence resolving the Promise with this stale value doesn’t update the DataGrid. Good answer though +1.

Also this solution still causes a re-render. This is bad for UX as users have to re-scroll to the original editing position again and again to continue editing.

@ChukwujiobiCanon I've made some additional changes to the solution. I think this should nail it down

With this new edit, row updates do not show on the DataGrid at all. For it to show, I must call setRows() and upsert newRow in processRowUpdate(). Guess what happens? You guessed it; a re-render. It is so frustrating.

With this new edit, rows are updated internally in the DataGrid and updated ref on parent component without re-render.
Check this fork: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-data-grid-forked-ssr8r3

Increase your rows to 25 in length.

The CodeSandBox instance has now 25 rows, I still don't see component re-rendered.
How did you come to the conclusion, that row updates do not show on the DataGrid at all or that the component re-rendered

There is also a way to update the const apiRef = useGridApiRef() manually
like this, apiRef.current.updateRows([updatedRow as GridRowModelUpdate])
However, I do not believe that it is necessary as they seem to be able to effectively manage internal changes.

It works in the sandbox indeed but I cannot replicate it in my environment. Thanks a lot for this. It’s my bedtime and I feel a bit sleepy. I’ll continue fighting this tomorrow.

What version of MUI do you have installed?

As you can see in the package.json
"@mui/x-data-grid": "7.4.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.15.14",
If you are still having trouble implementing the solution, you can share your code or something that resembles it.

This is incredible! I’ll run a few more tests and give my findings. But so far so good.

Thank you so much. Your solution made me rethink what I was doing. The Key is to disallow any form of state update within a ReactNode because it will require a GUI re-render. You should also consider adding this in your answer for posterity.

Happy to hear you could resolve the issue, I'll add a note regarding the state update and re-rendering
